# Is there a way to catch the transition of a SharePoint 2013 list item to Project Server 2013 project event?

Tags: splistitem, list-item, project-server

As you may know, there is a feature in SharePoint 2013 that allows you to create a project in PWA from a list item (Ideation). I need to add a couple more settings for that list item and the resulted project when that is created. Is there any way to know when that occurs? Or any other time, is there a PSI call available to check if a project is a result of transitioning a list item or an API call to check if a certain list item was transitioned to a project? I need to add a record in my DB to connect the two entities. Thanks.